# Duplicate Insert in transaction

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, database, sqltransaction

I have scenario in which I got multiple records inserted into the Table even the checks are implemented, I explain the flow of the code below.

```
BEGIN Transection;
var model = select id from table1 where outlet_code = 123 and survey_id = 5
if(model){
     throw new Exception("Outlet is already Surveyed.");
}else{
     INSERT Record into the table
} 
Commit Transection;
```

Problem:
I am getting multiple requests from the mobile side to upload survey, but the problem occur when I got multiple request with same outlet code.

```
First  Request outlet_code = 123abc and survey_id = 5
Second Request outlet_code = 123abc and survey_id = 5
```

Point is that Second request should not be inserted in the code however in some situations both records get inserted into the "table1"

I tested this scenario, but I got the exception which is fine, but there are records in the Database which violates this condition and I got both records in the database

kindly suggest what I am doing wrong,I just have an idea that it might be the problem of transaction committing order but I don't know how to solve this situation.

Database is SQL server 2008.

Comment: `PRIMARY KEY WITH(IGNORE_DUP_KEY=ON)` ?

Comment: what db you are using 1.) mysql 2.) postgresql or ????

Comment: If you are using postgresql then use : UPSERT : it will modified if data is already exit or if not it will insert in table

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and cleanest way would be creating a primary key on ID columnn so table won't accept any inserts with duplicating IDs. This will throw an error though on a second insert so it should be  handled as well.

Comment: actually there are three columns
id -- pk
outlet_code --- varchar
survey_id  ------ varchar

id is auto increment, the only thing i dont want is another record with same surevey_id and same outlet_code

Comment: then create an unique constraint on those columns: ALTER TABLE table_name ADD CONSTRAINT constr_name UNIQUE(outlet_code, surevey_id); --not sure if this is excactly the same in sql-server but you get the idea